# What is a Hope & Love Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with **Number** version puzzles.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Hope & Love Number™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Hope & Love Numbers™ | Not Hope & Love Numbers™ |
| --- | --- |
| 27 | 26 |
| 39 | 38 |
| 81 | 80 |
| 199 | 198 |
| 230 | 229 |
| 596 | 595 |
| 954 | 953 |
| 1490 | 1489 |
| 1705 | 1704 |
| 2509 | 2508 |
| 3002 | 3001 |
| 3900 | 3899 |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Hope & Love Numbers™,Not Hope & Love Numbers™
27,26
39,38
81,80
199,198
230,229
596,595
954,953
1490,1489
1705,1704
2509,2508
3002,3001
3900,3899
```

Comment: +1: Nice to see a number version :)

Comment: @Supersonic Because I'm at my wit's end with thinking new puzzle for Word version currently :P.

Comment: @Conifers does hope and & love is having anything to do with it? or you just named it randomly?

Comment: @SayedMohdAli The title is always the first hint for the puzzle :D

Comment: @Conifers yes, that is what I am thinking :P but  I thought it would be easier to ask maybe I am wrong :P lot of time will get wasted...

Comment: The first hint is usually more implicit... New hint will be released later if no proper answer comes out :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Hope & Love number

> has 5 letters in its Roman numeral representation.

Examples:

> 27 = XXVII, 39 = XXXIX, 81 = LXXXI, 199 = CXCIX, 230 = CCXXX, 596 = DXCVI, 954 = CMLIV, 1490 = MCDXC, 1705 = MDCCV, 2509 = MMDIX, 3002 = MMMII, 3900 = MMMCM

Counterexamples:

> 26 = XXVI, 38 = XXXVIII,80 = LXXX, 198 = CXCVIII, 229 = CCXXIX, 595 = DXCV, 953 = CMLIII, 1489 = MCDLXXXIX, 1704 = MDCCIV, 2508 = MMDVIII, 3001 = MMMI, 3899 = MMMDCCCXCIX

Possible title explanation *(thanks Stiv!)*

> Romans 5's chapter title is "Peace and Hope", which is somewhat close to "Hope and Love".
>  Alternatively, the passage in Romans 5:5 involves both hope and love.

Comment: Nice one +1 Re the title, rot13(V guvax lbh fubhyq ybbx hc gur puncgre urnqvat sbe Ebznaf 5 va n Ovoyr!)

Comment: Yes, and God bless you!